# .htaccess rule fails on server if using optional trailing slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following set of .htaccess rules

```
RewriteRule ^$ /?lang=en [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/?$ /?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*?)/?$ /?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /?lang=en&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The last rule is the newest to be implemented and is meant to be a fallback for if no language code was supplied to attempt serving the page using the default language.

The first 3 rules work perfectly in production and on local but when introducing the 4th rule it breaks. But it only breaks when the trailing slash is optional... if the trailing slash is omitted completely it is broken and if it is optional it is broken but if it is enforced it works. However this of course has the side effect of requiring a trailing slash in order for the rule to be met.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /?lang=en&page=$1 [L,QSA] DOES NOT WORK (500 ERROR)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /?lang=en&page=$1 [L,QSA] DOES NOT WORK (500 ERROR)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /?lang=en&page=$1 [L,QSA] WORKS BUT REQUIRES TRAILING SLASH
```

Whats going on? TIA

Comment: You create an endless rewriting loop with that last rule. ``(.*?)`` will match _any_ request so also those you just rewrote. You need to add conditions to prevent that.

Comment: BTW: A look into your http server's error log file would have told you that exact reason. Start monitoring that file!

Comment: @arkascha I knew I was tired last night and just needed to walk away! That makes sense. https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ this htaccess tester was throwing me off by saying it was a valid rule and matching the items I wanted but of course, we loop back in to the htaccess after the rewrite and then it will be matched for the rewritten rules! Would you kindly point me in the right direction for fixing this set of rules? Thanks!

Comment: Use a RewriteCond before the rule, to check if the query string does not contain the `lang` parameter already.